# Displaying a JSON value in a table in a particular color (red or green) based on conditions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON message that needs to be displayed in a table format as follows. I am trying to display MARKS, PERCENATGE, RESULT columns in different colors based on values. Anything below 40% is Fail and so marks, percentage and result values for Rick will be displayed in Red color where as for rest of students those three columns should be in green color.

Required table:

```
NAME     SEX    MARKS   PERCENTAGE   RESULT
Rick      M    32/100      32          F
Rose      F    43/45       95.96       P
Alex      M    54/75       72          P
Adam      M    88/96       91.67       P
```

JSON message:

```
[{"NAME":"Rick","SEX":"M","MARKS":"32/100","PERCENTAGE":"32%","RESULT":"F"},{"NAME":"Rose","SEX":"F","MARKS":"43/45","PERCENTAGE":"95.56%","RESULT":"P"},{"NAME":"Alex","SEX":"M","MARKS":"54/75","PERCENTAGE":"72%","RESULT":"P"},{"NAME":"Adam","SEX":"M","MARKS":"88/96","PERCENTAGE":"91.67%","RESULT":"P"}]
```

I have already written the following code which displays the data in a table format.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring Session Report</title>
    <style>
        table, th, td 
        {
            margin:10px 0;
            border:solid 1px #333;
            padding:2px 4px;
            font:15px Verdana;
            text-align: center;
        }
        th {
            font-weight:bold;
            background-color:#b1babf;
            color: black; 
            font-size: 15px;
            text-align: center;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 8px;
            height: 5px;
            width: 20%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="CreateTableFromJSON()" value="Generate Semester Report" />
    <div id="showData"></div>
</body>

<script>
    function CreateTableFromJSON() {

    var myBooks = [{"NAME":"Rick","SEX":"M","MARKS":"32/100","PERCENTAGE":"32%","RESULT":"F"},{"NAME":"Rose","SEX":"F","MARKS":"43/45","PERCENTAGE":"95.56%","RESULT":"P"},{"NAME":"Alex","SEX":"M","MARKS":"54/75","PERCENTAGE":"72%","RESULT":"P"},{"NAME":"Adam","SEX":"M","MARKS":"88/96","PERCENTAGE":"91.67%","RESULT":"P"}]

        var col = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < myReport.length; i++) {
            for (var key in myReport[i]) {
                if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                    col.push(key);
                }
            }
        }

        var table = document.createElement("table");

        var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                 

        for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
            var th = document.createElement("th");     
            th.innerHTML = col[i];
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < myReport.length; i++) {

            tr = table.insertRow(-1);

            for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                tabCell.innerHTML = myReport[i][col[j]];
            }
        }

        var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
        divContainer.innerHTML = "";
        divContainer.appendChild(table);

 }
</script>
</html>
```

I know that the color of the MARKS, PERCENTAGE, RESULT columns needs to be done with CSS but I am not sure how to achieve it. Or is there a better way to do it? Can anyone help in this regard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the percentage on each iteration, and give each `tr` a `pass` or `fail` class depending on whether the percentage. Then you can style the last few `TD`s with `nth-child`.

You can also significantly clean up your Javascript by using array methods:

```js
function CreateTableFromJSON() {
  var myBooks=[{"NAME":"Rick","SEX":"M","MARKS":"32/100","PERCENTAGE":"32%","RESULT":"F"},{"NAME":"Rose","SEX":"F","MARKS":"43/45","PERCENTAGE":"95.56%","RESULT":"P"},{"NAME":"Alex","SEX":"M","MARKS":"54/75","PERCENTAGE":"72%","RESULT":"P"},{"NAME":"Adam","SEX":"M","MARKS":"88/96","PERCENTAGE":"91.67%","RESULT":"P"}]
  const divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
  divContainer.textContent = '';
  const table = divContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("table"));
  const trHead = table.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
  Object.keys(myBooks[0]).forEach(key => {
    trHead.appendChild(document.createElement('th'))
      .textContent = key;
  });
  myBooks.forEach((personData) => {
    const tr = table.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
    const percentStr = personData.PERCENTAGE;
    const percent = Number(percentStr.slice(0, percentStr.length - 1));
    if (percent < 40) tr.className = 'fail';
    else tr.className = 'pass';
    Object.values(personData).forEach(tableValue => {
      tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
        .textContent = tableValue;
    });
  });
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: solid 1px #333;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  font: 15px Verdana;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #b1babf;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 8px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 20%;
}
tr.pass > td:nth-child(n + 3) {
  color: green;
}
tr.fail > td:nth-child(n + 3) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="CreateTableFromJSON()" value="Generate Semester Report" />
<div id="showData"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have two classes, one for each possible color:

```
.red {
    background: red;
}

.green {
    background: green;
}
```

Then, depending on whether the percentage is below `40%`, you apply one or the other:

```
const percentage = parseFloat(student.PERCENTAGE); // No need to remove the % at the end.

tableCell.classList.add(percentage < 40 ? 'red' : 'green')
```

Full example:

```js
// Data:

const students = [{
  "NAME":"Rick",
  "SEX":"M",
  "MARKS":"32/100",
  "PERCENTAGE":"32%",
  "RESULT":"F"
}, {
  "NAME":"Rose",
  "SEX":"F",
  "MARKS":"43/45",
  "PERCENTAGE":"95.56%",
  "RESULT":"P"
}, {
  "NAME":"Alex",
  "SEX":"M",
  "MARKS":"54/75",
  "PERCENTAGE":"72%",
  "RESULT":"P"
}, {
  "NAME":"Adam",
  "SEX":"M",
  "MARKS":"88/96",
  "PERCENTAGE":"91.67%",
  "RESULT":"P"
}];

// Get a list with all column names:
const columnNames = Object.keys(students[0]);

// And create another one with the ones we want to add a background based
// on the value of the percentage:
const columnNamesWithBackground = ["MARKS", "PERCENTAGE", "RESULT"];

// Create the table:

const table = document.createElement("table");

// Create the header of the table:

const header = table.insertRow();

for (const columnName of columnNames) {
  const th = document.createElement("th"); 
  
  th.innerText = columnName;
  
  header.appendChild(th);
}

// Create the content of the table:

for (const student of students) {

  // Add a new row at the end:
  tr = table.insertRow(-1);

  // Get the percentage and parse it as a number:
  const percentage = parseFloat(student.PERCENTAGE);

  // Add all the columns and values to this row:
  for (const columnName of columnNames) {
    const td = tr.insertCell(-1);
    
    if (columnName === 'SEX') {
      td.classList.add('borderRight');
    } else if (columnNamesWithBackground.includes(columnName)) {
      td.classList.add(percentage < 40 ? 'red' : 'green');
    }
    
    td.innerText = student[columnName];
  }  
}

// Add the table to the page:

document.body.appendChild(table);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
}

table {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 4px;
}

th {
  padding: 8px;
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF; 
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 20%;
}

.green {
  background: #0A2;
  color: #FFF;
}

.red {
  background: #F00;
  color: #FFF;
}

.borderRight {
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: @Danziger- Thank you for the example.